# Imprimir lo que haya en una etiqueta CANVAS de HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, print

Estoy tratando de imprimir el contenido de una etiqueta `div`de HTML, hasta allí todo va a la perfeción, entonces lo que estoy realizando por medio de la librería `fabricJS` es que se pueda escribir un texto y adicionar una imagen como se muestra a continuación:

**IMAGEN DEL CONTENIDO**
[image: FabricJS]

Pero, al tratar de imprimir el contenido del `div`, que abarca desde el hola mundo hasta la seccion del `canvas`me he topado con que el contenido del canvas no lo imprime y lo muestra en blanco:

**IMAGEN DE IMPRESIÓN**
[image: Printing]

**CÓDIGO HTML**

```
<div class="card mb-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
      <div class="container" id="print-section">
        ¡Hola Mundo!
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400px" height="100px" style="border:solid;">
          Hola Mundo!
        </canvas>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="print('printSectionId')">Print</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" (click)="inciarCanvas()">Etiqueta</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CÓDIGO TYPESCRIPT/ANGULAR**

```
canvas: any;
  constructor() { }
  print(): void {
    let printContents,
        popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
          </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', );
    this.canvas.add(new fabric.IText('¡Escribe lo que tu quieras!'));
    fabric.Image.fromURL('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/emoji/unicode/1f47d.png', (image) => {
      image.set({
        left: 50,
        top: 70,
      });

      this.canvas.add(image);
    });
  }
```

> **Nota:** Si presiono las teclas `ctrl` + `p` se muestra todo el contenido de la página, incluido el canvas y que hay cargado en el
>   canvas.

¿Qué puedo realizar para solucionar esto, o que sugerencias me pueden dar para obtener lo que pretendo?

¡De antemano, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para los que lleguen hasta aquí con el mismo problema, dejo la solucion para imprimir los objetos que se hayan generado con la librería `FabricJS`:

Para la solución usé el método de `FabricJS`con denominación `toSVG`

```
rasterizeSVG ()
  {
    let printContents,
        popupWin,
        img;
    printContents = this.canvas.toSVG();
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>
          </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`);
    popupWin.document.close();
    return 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(this.canvas.toSVG())
  }
```

**Detalle**

Entonces, hacemos que el objeto de HTML sea igual al canvas haciendo la respectiva llamada al metodo de conversión de SVG `this.canvas.toSVG();`. En pocas palabras lo que hacemos es convertir el contenido de la etiqueta `canvas` a un formato `svg` por lo que al realizar la impresión este lo obtiene en dicho formato mencionado con anterioridad.

En esta sección del código retornamos la imagen y la codificamos con componente SVG para darle la respectiva salida.

```
return 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(this.canvas.toSVG())
```

> **Nota:** Si me he equivocado en algún término me lo hacen saber, gracias!